# Handllebar helper returns additional window url path for href

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

When i return a href using handlebar helper in a Node Express.js, the embeded URL is referring additional path.

The routing url is like `router.get('/view/:id')` and actual url is `http://localhost:3000/view/5c653ffb58ff1515c0a51203`

And my handlebar helper which return a href is

```
cturb: function(value, options) {
    var html = [];
    var value = value + '';
    if ((value == 'Applicable for all Turbines') || (value == 'Not Applicable')) {
        return "<ul class=\"custom-bullet\"><li>" + value + "</li></ul>";
    } else if (value) {
        var value = value.split(",");
        var length = value.length; 

        html.push("<ul class=\"custom-bullet\">");
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          html.push('<li><a href="turbine/turc' + value[i] + '">' + value[i] + '</a></li>');
        } html.push("</ul>");
         
    }
    try {
        return html.join('');
    } catch (e) {
        return 'error';
    }

}
```

The html returned looks like `<a href="view/turbine/turcV100/test">test</a>`

but it should be

```
<a href="turbine/turcV100/test">test</a>
```

I am not sure why the extra path view is added.

Comment: what the data you are getting from value looks like?

Comment: here i am sending an array to the cturb helper. the array value looks like ["V1", "V2", ...]